# なぜエラーが起きているのかわかりません: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Tags: javascript, laravel

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
```

が出ているのですが・・・
なぜエラーとなっているのかわかりません。
JS上で何かミスっている気がします。

```
<script>
    function createLink(){
        const div3 = document.getElementById("div3");
        if (!div3.hasChildNodes()){
            const a1 = document.createElement("a");
            a1.href = '"' +{{ route('alink')}} + '"';
            a1.innerText = "itsakura";
            div3.appendChild(a1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: エラーメッセージは「:」が予期しない場所に書かれているとなっていますが、ご提示のソースにはコロン記載箇所がありません。エラー発生個所は本当に提示ソース内なのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

Laravel のことはさっぱり知りませんが、

```js
            a1.href = '"' +{{ route('alink')}} + '"';
```

`{{ route('alink')}}` が URL に展開されて  `= '"' + http://example.com/ + '"'` のようになっているのでは。自分が編集しているソースファイルではなく、ブラウザの機能でソースを確認してみてください。